# Why don't we use "express.use" in NodeJS applications?

Tags: node.js, express

I have seen something like this in a NodeJS application:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Why didn't it use express like below:

```
const express = require('express');
express.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: Why *would* you use it like that? That's just not the API the library exposes.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I feel that your edit has removed some important context for the confusion.  I don't think that there were really multiple questions here.

Comment: @Brad the part I deleted was not at all clear to me, I think the OP would benefit most from just reading up on the module system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When we call `require('express')`, we're essentially loading the module so that we can use it.

Express is set up in a way that its default export is a function that when called returns a fresh instance of Express.

Some applications may want to use multiple instances, which is why we wouldn't use `express.use()`.