# Express JS Basic Routing Template

Tags: express, routes

Can someone explain this to me clearly?

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
```

I get the first line of code, but don't get the concept of initializing a variable "app" as express()? When we import express, we also have access to express()?

What does it do theoretically? What does that () of express() do? 
Do we always have to do it like that?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't we use "express.use" in NodeJS applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59512833/why-dont-we-use-express-use-in-nodejs-applications)

Comment: I don't really get it, can you explain it more?

Comment: @KeKe - In this statement `const express = require("express");`, `express` is a "factory function".  Look that term up if you don't know it.  When you call it, it creates and returns an instance of an express `app` object.  Until you call it, it's just a function waiting to be called and there are no working instances of express apps.  The reason that it doesn't make an instance for you is that there are some cases where you want to make multiple apps (like both `http` and `https` servers listening on different ports so you need the ability to make your own instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are familiar with object-oriented programming, then the way to think of this is by creating an instance.

When you import express, you are importing the class. However, your server is an instance of that class. So, when you call

```js
const app = express();
```

you are spinning up your server. You now have the encoding of a server you can interact with from `app`, whereas the original import just refers to the same class (i.e. like a template) for what that server is. The function `express()` is merely initializing a new server object for you.

Technically, you could have multiple 'servers' running:

```js
const app1 = express();
const app2 = express();
```

You would want these to be independent of each other, which is why you don't just use the top-level import.

Comment: so app = express () essentially creates an object of Express - a "server" - which would be independent from other objects once they are made. Did I understand this?

Comment: @KeKe yes, you're understanding is correct on that aspect. Each instance returned by `express()` will be independent of the other.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app)

> The express() function is a top-level function exported by the express module

The function returns a app object which is essentially an Express application.

> The app object has methods for
>
> - Routing HTTP requests; see for example, app.METHOD and app.param.
> - Configuring middleware
> - Rendering HTML views; see
> - Registering a template engine; see app.engine.

Comment: but what did the other guy mean by "multiple instances of express"?

Comment: like we can't do express.get / express.set / express.listen etc?

Comment: Multiple instances are multiple apps running on the same Node process. Like @BT99 points in his answer, these apps could be running on different ports with their own or shared routing, middlewares, views